# Clean, low-overhead way to send an email when a mysql/mariadb table is updated?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I need to send an email when a record is added to a table.

A bunch of googling has left me with the impression that the only choices are "bad" and "really bad" and was wondering if anybody had any clean, solid, reliable suggestions.

So far I've found:

- Use a mysql plugin that sends the mail. I'd rather not do this because I have a perfectly good mail server and the database wasn't designed to send mail.
- Poll the table periodically from an external program, look for changes and send the mail if appropriate. This is almost OK, but I'd rather skip the dead time between the record being added and the next poll.

I had considered using SELECT ... OUTFILE, however this is really limited because it won't overwrite the output file and the only way to change the filename is by building the query with dynamic SQL, which can't be used inside a trigger.

I could write a socket listener and have Mysql open the socket and tell the mail app there are records waiting, however there doesn't seem to be a way to open a socket from mysql.

It feels like I must be missing something here.

All I want is to run an external application when a record is added.

Has anybody run into a clean, low overhead way to do this?

Comment: What is adding the record to the table? Could whatever it is be modified to send the notification or call something else to do the sending?

Comment: @Dave IT's a database operation from a form submit in PHP. That's actually an interesting possibility. If I assume that an absence of an error in the PHP code indicates success, it would be easy enough to kick off the email process. OTOH, it would be nice if I could do it when the data actually changed instead of when I think it probably changed. However, it's a great idea. If it turns out I can't do it from the DB, this is the way I'll go.

Comment: If your update is wrapped in a try/catch block you will know it has succeeded when the transaction is committed (or the catch block is not hit).

Comment: @Dave I went with your original suggestion and wrote a daemon that does nothing but check the DB once/second to see if there's anything that needs handling. I was originally going to make it 1/5 seconds or 10 seconds, but the overhead is essentially 0 (it doesn't even bump the CPU or disk utilization), so I went 1/sec. It's working great and moved all the potentially failure-prone operations out of the DB. **please post your suggestion as an answer so I can upvote it and hit "accept"**. Thanks - Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code that is adding the record and have it do the notifications. If you put it in a try/catch block you will know for sure whether or not the record was added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger on table(s) of interest to insert into other table (email queue).
Create a scheduled process to process the other table.